# pandas, excel, поиск совпадений в различных столбцах

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, python-3.6

Здраствуйте, у меня есть файл типа:
[image: тестовые данные]

нужно сгруппировать 2-3 столбцы и выполнить поиск по всем столбцам и подсчитать количество совпадений. я разобрался как подсчитать количество совпадений в столбцах, которые группирую, вот пример кода:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ["result_df.xlsx"] #файли, які потрібнi
df = pd.read_excel(dates[0], dtype=str)
df1 = df.groupby(['b','c']).size()
df1.to_excel('result2.xlsx')
```

И вот что получаю:

[image]

Нужно сделать подсчет сгруппированных столбцов "b" i "c" по всему файла, вот пример как должны искаться данные и затем подсчитать количество таких совпадений, как на скриншоте2.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
[image: пример поиска]
Вот пример данных:

```
list_of_dicts = [
 {'a': 'Machine', 'b': '', 'c': 'Mess', 'd': 'Room', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Mess', 'b': 'Room', 'c': 'Portable', 'd': 'Galley', 'e': 'Equipment', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Fixed', 'b': 'Galley', 'c': 'Equipment', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Fryer', 'b': 'Fixed', 'c': 'Galley', 'd': 'Equipment', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Galley', 'b': 'Equipment', 'c': '', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Trash', 'b': 'and', 'c': 'Recycling', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Fixed', 'b': 'Galley', 'c': 'Equipment', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Disposal', 'b': 'Fixed', 'c': 'Galley', 'd': 'Equipment', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Fixed', 'b': 'Galley', 'c': 'Equipment', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Fixed', 'b': 'Galley', 'c': 'Equipment', 'd': '', 'e': '', 'f': ''},
 {'a': 'Machine', 'b': 'Mess', 'c': 'Room', 'd': 'Portable', 'e': 'Galley', 'f': 'Equipment'}

]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

Comment: По какому принципу вы игнорируете "черные" слова (не вошедшие в группировку)?

Comment: Как вы получили такую матрицу слов?

Comment: @MaxU , df.groupby(['b','c']).size() данный метод объединяет 2 столбца и ищет совпадения в этих двух столбцах и подсчитывает их. Игнорировать"черные" слова не нужно, нужно искать количество всех совпадений

Comment: Т.е. каждое сочетание проходится "скользящим окном" по столбцам в поисках совпадений?

Comment: @CrazyElf, не совсем понимаю выражение "скользящим окном"